# Qt catch shift + 3 on one key press

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ascii, keypress

I'm using Qt 5.11.

I need to catch `shift + 3` on one key press. But this combination generates special character `^` because I'm using Turkish Q Keyboard. So I can't catch it without press `shift + 3` again.

I tried shift modifiers and multiple key press solutions but not working.

I want to override `^`. Is there any possible ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it could work. Although according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#nativeVirtualKey), nativeVirtualKey could return 0 even if there is valid information. So not sure if it will work all the time. I tested it with a german, english and arabic keyboard.

Update (tested it with turkish keyboard layout)

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *ev)
{
    if ((ev->nativeVirtualKey() == Qt::Key_3 || ev->key() == Qt::Key_3)  && ev->modifiers()  == Qt::ShiftModifier)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

For turkish layout, ^ caret (a dead key), in addition to the above, you can catch the dead key press by overriding the nativeEvent function and calling the keyEvent function manually

```
bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
    MSG *msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if (msg->message == WM_DEADCHAR)
    {
        QKeyEvent *key = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_3, Qt::ShiftModifier);
    }
}
```

One minor issue, the keyEvent will be called even if ^ is pressed in another language, not necessarily only with Shift+3, so this is an unexpected behaviour, but maybe for your case you can tell the user that both shift+3 or ^ are the shortcut for your specific function

Comment: still have to press twice. I think I have to override much more deeper than qt functions. maybe windows' keyboard input functions.